# wallpaperManager.getDesiredMinimumWidth() returns -1 in device

Tags: android, wallpaper

I am trying to get the default wallpaper resolution of the phone using WallpaperManager.

```
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
Log.v("a",wallpaperManager.getDesiredMinimumWidth());
Log.v("a",wallpaperManager.getDesiredMinimumHeight());
```

Height returns 800 and Width returns 960 in the emulator but both returns -1 while running in the device.

I have SET_WALLPAPER permission in the manifest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#getDesiredMinimumWidth%28%29), that value is not mandatory (in which case a number <= 0 will be returned). If the value returned is less than or equal to zero, then you should use the width/height of the screen.

Comment: What is the best way to get the width/height of the screen?